# Initialising String with += expression returns "()"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[Start of app (Main storyboard but it's fine in simulator to.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixasf.png)

[After clicking play button in mutates into something that isn't a 1,2,3....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwRJJ.png)

Here is the code in the viewcontroller and it's not much. Pretty simple stopwatch app.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    var counter = 0
    var clock : Timer = Timer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        timeLabel.text = String(counter)
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func playButton(_ sender: Any) {
        clock = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func updateTimer(){
        timeLabel.text = String(describing: counter += 1)
    }

    @IBAction func pauseButton(_ sender: Any) {
        clock.invalidate()
    }

    @IBAction func resetButton(_ sender: Any) {
        clock.invalidate()
        counter = 0
        timeLabel.text = String(counter)
    }


}
```

I've tried setting constraints but that just shoots out "ambiguous" warnings all over the place. Any suggestions? Ideas?

Comment: `counter += 1` doesn't return a value, that is why you see `()`. Implementation of `+=` in `Swift` is different from that in `C`. That is what caused the issue. Separate it into 2 statements as pointed by Leo Dabus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at your updateTimer method. You need to move your variable increment to the line above and then create a string representation from the variable:

```
func updateTimer() {
    counter += 1
    timeLabel.text = String(counter)
}
```